# macOS Big Sur - Changing the system font

Tags: macos, big-sur, customization

I would like to change the system font (Menu Bar included) to Lucida Grande.

I have SIP disabled, and I've also disabled Library Validation.

Thanks!

Comment: Apple make it very, very difficult to do this. The security and integrity of the OS is increasingly strengthened with each new OS. If you can find a way to do this in Big Sur, the chances are that method won't work next year. If you want an OS with a customized GUI, then macOS isn't it.